# Xcode 4.2 requires first letter as lowercase for Core Data Attributes

Tags: ios, core-data

Does anyone know why Xcode 4.2 is requiring an attribute name to start with a lowercase letter in core data model? Will there be any issue going forward?

Comment: [Convention over configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration), perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

It has always been this way because Objective-C standard naming conventions recommend a lower case first letter for iVars, properties, etc.  Core Data is just enforcing that recommendation.

Comment: But how do you turn it off?  I have a project where previous versions of xcode/coredata did not require upper case characters, but now it is forcing me, so my model does not look consistent.

Comment: I doubt that you can turn it off.  You could file a radar but I am not sure how much traction you would get with it.

Comment: The other proposed answer shows that there are two places to enter the name.  One checks the case but the second does not.  So by using the second entry, you have essentially disabled the check.

Comment: Which would just be supporting broken behavior.  Do not use upper case attributes.  It is against convention and is going to cause problems later when that hole is closed and you are faced with a difficulty in migration.

Comment: I wouldn't call it broken behavior, just a naming convention.  If they close the workaround then you'll have to rename your attributes in both code and coredata to what Apple forces on us.

Comment: For a property beginning with an acronym, initial uppercase is the correct choice, e.g. `HTTPMethod`, `URLString`, `TIFFRepresentation`.

Answer (score 2):

While you should generally follow the recommended naming convention, if you need to get around this, you can enter a beginning uppercase character in the "Name" attribute of the "Data Model Inspector" (the inspector is in the right hand pane).  Where the Core Data attribute editor will not allow you to enter something uppercase as the first character, the inspector will allow it.

Answer (score 0):

If you go into the terminal and find the xcdatamodel/contents and edit it (I used vi) you can find the name you have and change it.